# How to skip first empty line in XML file in Pentaho kettle transformation?

Tags: pentaho-design-studio, pentaho-spoon

I am working with the XML file format. My file is similar to this; the first line is blank.  How can I skip the empty line?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Level1>
 <Level2>
   <Props>
    <ObjectID>AAAAA</ObjectID>
    <SAPIDENT>31-8200</SAPIDENT>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Merkmalname>TX_B</Merkmalname>
    <Merkmalswert> 600</Merkmalswert>
   </Props>
   <Props>
    <ObjectID>AAAAA</ObjectID>
    <SAPIDENT>31-8200</SAPIDENT>
    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    <Merkmalname>TX_B</Merkmalname>
    <Merkmalswert> 900</Merkmalswert>
   </Props>
 </Level2></Level1>
```

Comment: I think you need to show problems which you have

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please make sure your question is actually phrased as a question.

Comment: my input file has 1st row blank and while transformation m getting  Error   Could not open file #1:file:abc.xml>org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 2 of document file:/UTF-8:The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. Nested exception: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
Error on line 2 of document file:/UTF-8:The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. Nested exception:The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Comment: if i am removing 1st blank line then , working fine